# How does the Java Sound API avoid echoes？

Tags: java, javasound

I'm making a microphone intercom program, function development using the Sound API.

**Play the other person's voice：**

```
AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(16000.0F, 16, 1, true, false);
    SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;
    DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat, AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED);
    sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
    sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
    sourceDataLine.start();
    while(true) sourceDataLine.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length); //write audio data
```

**Collect the microphone's voice data and send it to the other party:**

```
AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(16000.0F, 16, 1, true, false);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);
TargetDataLine targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
targetDataLine.start();
System.out.println("You can speak now!");
int nByte = 0;
final int bufSize = 3200;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
while ((nByte = targetDataLine.read(buffer, 0, bufSize)) > 0) {
    //send.....
}
```

**question:**
At the same time as playing the other party's voice, the acquisition microphone sends the other party's voice to the other party. What should I do about it? Thanks.

Comment: From what I can tell, you are asking how to do both of these at the same time? If this is the case, then use multithreading.

Comment: @CureMe It's using multithreading, that's not the point.

Comment: I think by 'echoes' you mean audio feedback from the speaker to the mic? It's not a trivial task to subtract the inbound sound from the microphone signal. Java Sound has no inbuilt functionality for that. It does, however, provide access to the raw streams so the programmer could (theoretically) write the code themselves.

Comment: @AndrewThompson regardless of the external echo, using the above code, the echo is generated inside the computer, I wonder how to access the microphone raw stream ?